# jQuery DataTable exact match

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatables

I have this jQuery datatable in place:

```
 var $dataTable = $('#example1').DataTable({
   "ajax": serviceUrl,
   "iDisplayLength": 25,
   "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
   "scrollY": 600,
   "scrollX": true,
   "bDestroy": true
});
```

I also have this CHANGE event happening when the user selects an option in a dropdown:

```
 $('#serviceload').on('change',function()
 {
   $dataTable.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
 });
```

I need to be able to alter the CHANGE event so that it searches the DataTable for the exact match in the dropdown.

For example, the v has 2 services called SERV and SERV_ONE.  In the dropdown, both SERV and SERV_ONE are available for the user to choose, but if the user chooses SERV, the datatable filters for SERV and also displays the records for SERV_ONE.  But when SERV_ONE is chosen, the DataTable only displays the records for SERV_ONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) for proper use of drop-down filters.

```
$('#serviceload').on('change keyup', function(){
   var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
   $dataTable
     .columns(1)
     .search( val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false )
     .draw();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  I did find my way to that link you provided, but I could not get my data to load using that method.  I tried to apply the code you provided above into my CHANGE event, but the results are the same.  Definitely promising though.

Comment: Sorry...the code was unsuccessful.  I'm still returning the same results.  I'm playing around with the code.  Hopefully your code will help me find the resolution.  Thank you so much for your help.  Upvote to you.